# Can I download a Google spreadsheet as a CSV rather than HTML?

Tags: r, google-docs

I am desperately trying to load a CSV file from google drive into R.  Why is it returning HTML?

```
daily_activity<- 
read.csv("https://drive.google.com/file/d/10CwoOyJMMA6MZ1csQOFJ7YavbN3Z9z1W/view?usp=sharing")
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you ....i was trying to create a markdown and thats why I had the extra characters....thank you again kind sir ..I will try this :)

Comment: standby, though, that link is not going to work without auth ...

Comment: Change to my last: go to https://sites.google.com/site/gdocs2direct/home, paste in the original URL, then copy the "output link" text it provides.

Comment: Have you looked at the [googlesheets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googlesheets/) package?

Comment: Im still struggling I added my google drive package and I will try the google sheets package now

Comment: @Brandy Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `Please do not reword questions. I know this is possible as I was instructed, but had trouble mapping the drive. With all due respect please comment or further probe to find out what is happening. Thank you all.`, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. By this, I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: @Brandy By the way, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your comment to my answer of `Please do not reword questions.`. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike no problem I understand.  You should not ask Can I if you know you can.  I need to know what I was doing wrong and it was my file structure.  Thank you very much for responding.

Comment: @Brandy Thank you for replying. I understood your current situation for your question. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.